# Opening and Closing Full Screen Div with Transforms Applied

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I have multiple elements that each have multiple CSS transforms applied along with perspective and I'm having a hard time getting them to line up when each element expands and contracts to/from full screen back to its original size/position. To do the full screen animation I'm using FSM JS which creates a copy of the original element to do the full screen animation.

I'm using CSS animation to tweak the copied full screen element to match the transformations applied to the original element. Expanding seems to work fine enough but when it shrinks back I can't get the animation to line up properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Hopefully this makes at least a little bit of sense. I think it will be clear when you see my code at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQQYaE.

Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="tiltview">
        <a class="fsm" href="#">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=1073" />
        </a>
        <a class="fsm" href="#">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=1080" />
        </a>
        <a class="fsm" href="#">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=1075" />
        </a>
        <a class="fsm">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=1079" />
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's a snippet of the CSS:

```
section {
    perspective: 1600px;
}
.tiltview {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;    
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(35deg);
    z-index: 0;
}

.fsm {
    margin: 1vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    outline: 1px solid yellow;

    &.growing {     
        animation: modalAnimation 1s ease reverse;
    }

    &.full-screen {
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 100;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    &.shrinking {
        animation: modalAnimation 1s ease forwards;
    }
}   

img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

@keyframes modalAnimation {
    to {
        transform: translate3d(10%, -30%, 0) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(35deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be little more clear what do you mean by **"when it shrinks back to it's "original" size the element is smaller."**, as shrinking means getting smaller. BTW I checked the demo it looks like your div is shrinking but not the image, to achieve the images shrinking, consider giving the images `height` and `width` set to `100%`

Comment: I mistakenly removed img { width:100% } from the CSS. The image shrinks now. I don't want to specify height and width because I'm going to be using the code for different sized images in different places.